# Report Builder: Explicit X-axis range definition?

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder, reportbuilder3.0

I'm assembling a set of charts that query the same data, but with differing filters. For some of the filtered datasets, there is limited data, and for the charts displaying that data their minimum value on the X-axis is simply set to the minimum value found in the dataset. For consistency, I would like to explicitly set those bounds to the parameters passed to the report, however unlike the Y-axis the X-axis seems to lack this capability. Are there options that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the `Series Group` properties ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have no issues in setting an expression in the x-axis properties dialog box and as such using a parameter there also. I've done it and the links below provide some sense that the option is there.

[Axis Properties Dialog Box, Axis Options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220560%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

I suspect what they are talking about, or at least how you can do this as far as I know, is to use these parameters in the dataset itself as the x-axis will be set based on the dataset alone.

Whereas the vertical axis is, or at least can be, unbound to your values. I mean that you may have values in the positive but decide not to display them by forcing the chart to show only negatives, due to say a KPI that is needed.